# Concurrent request handling in MVC3 / EF4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4, concurrency

I have a list of `Games` users can join. To select a `game`, they have to pick a `position` (ie., role) within that game.

**Model**

```
[Game] 1 <-> * [PlayerGame] * <-> 0..1 [Player]
```

The PlayerGame entity defines the picked position by the player.

**Other details**

- All the games are listed within a MVC 3 View.
- Data is persisted within a SQL Server 2008 instance and accessed via EF4 (CodeFirst).
- The view updates itself via some jQuery Get() calls that pulls up-to-date data each **N** milliseconds.
- The higher the delay (**N**), the bigger the chances of racing conditions, where 2 users would try to pick the same position.
- I will obviously need to do some server-side validation to allow only one of the 2 users to get the selected position, if they both pick the same position at the same time.

**What would be the best way to asses only 1 person gets the selected position while the other gets an error message?**

I'm currently thinking about using TimeStamps to make sure only **1** of the 2 calls can successfully update the PlayerGame row. Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use timestamps. That is the way which is usually used and both SQL server (any database server) and EF supports them. You will have to roundtrip timestamp to the client and use it when constructing entity to be updated (in detached scenario).

Comment: The main issue i see with TimeStamps is that I have to create every PlayerGame entity at the same time I create a game. Thus PlayerGame.PlayerId has to be nullable. It's not a big deal at all though!

Answer (score 1):

From your question I can assume you also have a `[Positions]` table? if not, where are those coming from?

So you don't really have to have a timestamp right? Just before you persist your entity, do something like `entity.List().Where(x => x.GameId == requestedGameId && x.PositionId == requestedPositionId)`

Then if you receive null and it does not exist yet its safe to submit, if you do receive an entity the position is already taken.

*Note: I'm not that familiar with the entity framework syntax, just guessing what it'd be like, but you probably get when I mean with my pseudocode*

Comment: Yes, there is a Position value, it is an attribute of PlayerGame. The problem with your solution is that the check to see if the Position is already taken by Player A could be done at the same time as Player B tries to update the row (or, say, 1 ms after). Those racing conditions would mean that Player A wouldn't get an error message, yet his position would be stolen by Player B, and I obviously don't want that.

Comment: Ok well, another solution is just add a candidate key on both `GameId` and the `PositionId` on the database layer. (which is like a unique constraint of multiple columns) that way if Player B tries to insert and that combination already exists the sql server will refuse.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea! Not sure how I would generate this key using CodeFirst... I will have to see if it is simplier than using TimeStamps, thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: If the entity framework does not recreate your database all the time, you could just manually implement it on your database. However, if EF assumes it can insert but receives an error from the server it will probably throw an exception.

Comment: Also, imo having this rule implemented on the deepest level (your sql server) seems like a good practice. That way even if data is inserted from somewhere else (like a direct query), you are still ensured its correct and not conflicting with rules you have implemented in an higher level such as in your EF